# Compiling Erlang module using erl.exe

Tags: compilation, erlang, erlang-shell

I am extremely new to Erlang, I am trying to compile my first Erlang module and am getting an error that the no such file exists, although it does in fact exist.

Any suggestions as to why I erl.exe is failing to compile `useless.erl` is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

erl.exe command prompt (note modules does in fact contain useless.erl)

```
1> filename:absname("C:/Users/modules"). 
"C:/Users/modules"
2> c(useless). 
useless.erl:none: no such file or directory
```

(useless.erl)

```
-module(useless).
-export([add/2, hello/0, greet_and_add_two/1]).

add(A,B) ->
A + B.

%% Shows greetings.
%% io:format/1 is the standard function used to output text.
hello() ->
io:format("Hello, world!~n").

greet_and_add_two(X) ->
hello(),
add(X,2).
```

Comment: How have you created `useless.erl`? Some Windows editor are "text" editors and automatically append `.txt` to the file nane. So in your case the file would actually be named `useless.erl.txt` which erlang won't find.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, useless ends with .erl only and has an erlang icon on it, no .txt extension.

Comment: `filename:absname/1` does not actually change the directory. I think you need to `cd("c:/users/modules").`

Comment: Yes, of course. I should have seen that as well.

Comment: @Shane Charles, Thanks for the reply! That worked for changing the directory. However, I am currently getting the error: `useless.bea#: error writing file` at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that form, you need to execute `erl` the same directory as the module you are trying to compile. You can specify a file path when you use the `c` function.  This will create a `.beam` file in your current directory:

```
Erlang R16B (erts-5.10.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V5.10.1  (abort with ^G)
1> c("stackoverflow/passfun.erl").
{ok,passfun}
2> passfun:some_func().
hello
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This did not work for me. I was unable to execute the `c` command. I get the following error `useless.bea#: error writing file`

Comment: Where are you running `erl` from? You probably don't have permission to write to your current directory.

Comment: +1, Thank you! Permissions was in fact the problem, once I ran `erl.exe` as admin, all worked well.